# Are there any programs on the internet that show step by step how to convert a formula to Conjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, math-software

## Step by step generator for CNF in propositional logic?

I am looking for software like Symbolab except for propositional logic.

When given a formula in propositional logic the software should output steps for converting the formula into Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF).

---

below is the output of this imaginary program when given the formula:

$$(a \lor b)\implies (\lnot a \implies b) $$

[image]

The software can be in any language.

Comment: I'm don't know any software, however, this problem feels like it should be quite trivial... Just consider the most prominent operator of the formula, and work your way to the bottom recursively. If you store the formula in a convenient way, such that the most prominent operator is readily accessible, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Let me add, "quite trivial" is meant as finding a solution. Finding an *efficient* solution will most liikely be NP-complete

Comment: Polytime (and consequently, space) conversions to cnf are known, that's why NP-completeness is often described in terms of 3-cnf.

Comment: @DanielV NP completeness of 3-SAT means there is a polynomial time conversion to an *equisatisfiable* CNF formula, not necessarily to an equivalent one.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah thanks that is an important distinction I wasn't thinking about.  But if I recall correctly, the common algorithms create a formula with a superset of variables such that any satisfying assignment to the superset will also satisfy the original formula.  I wonder if that would work for whatever task the poster has in mind?